# Why SQL Server 2008 Management Studio doesn't have option "Open table"

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

I used to have option to open table in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio, but don't have that anymore in the 2008 version. Does anybody know why this option has been removed? And, if this feature is no longer available in the 2008 version, what is the best alternative to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now it's `Edit Top 200 rows`.
They did this cause people were opening huge tables without thinking.
If you want to see 2000 rows, you can edit the select query when you right click -> pane -> SQL.

[image]

Then in your sql statement you will see `Top(200)`. you just have to change to the number of rows you need.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The option is still there, it's just been renamed.  I believe the old version used to attempt to get every single record in the table.  The revised SSMS will, by default, get only the first 200.

Right-click a table and select *Edit Top 200 Rows* as shown below:

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks but I know that already but it only let you edit top 200 rows what if I got 2000 rows :S

Comment: You can edit the query by clicking the "Show SQL Pane" button, or ALT + 3 on the keyboard. Better yet - use Query Analyzer and try not to rely on a GUI =)

Comment: @Ignacio - You can also set the N to use in the SSMS options. Set it to 0 to allow all rows but probably best to leave it as is and edit the query if needed.

Comment: I added a screen shot showing the button to click to show the SQL pane.

Answer (score 1):

its good to change it like-

tools-> options ->SQL server object explorer -> commands --in this we can edit for whichever rows..